# How to encode SQL Query result in a View using Yii 2.0?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, yii2

In Yii 2.0, I was trying to encode or print a query result to XML format in order to access to these data by using REST, but when I push the result of the query (located it in an `ActiveController`) into de view, I get a huge html code and the query result inside of it.

This is my `ActiveController`, and my function `actionSql()` to render the `sql.php` view:

```
class EventController extends ActiveController{

    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Event';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }


    public function actionSql(){
        $rows = (new Query())
        ->select(['ta.id', 'e.name', 'e.desc', 'u.place', 'u.date'])
        ->from(['ta' => 't_area'])
        ->innerJoin('event e', 'ta.id = e.t_area_id')
        ->innerJoin('ubic u', 'e.id = u.event_id')
        ->where([
            'ta.id' => 1,
            'dayname(u.date)' => 'Monday'
            ])
        ->all();

        return $this->render( 'sql', [
            'rows' => $rows,
        ]);
    }
}

===========================
sql.php (The View)

<?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\grid\GridView;
?>
<?php 
    foreach ($filas as $fila){
        foreach ( $fila as $key=>$value ){
            echo $key . ' => ' . $value . '<br>';
        } 
        echo '<br>';
    }
 ?>
```

Thank you so much. Hope to find the answer!

Comment: try to return rows without rendering them, `return $rows`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [renderPartial()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#renderPartial()-detail) to render your view without applying layout.

But the format you are using in your sql view is not XML...
You should try instead :

```
public function actionSql()
{
    $rows = ....... ;

    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML;
    return $rows;
}
```

Read more about response formats in [Yii2 Cookbook](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/response-formats.md#xml-response).

And you should also read this : [RESTful Web Services with Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your time buddies. The solution is to return rows variable:

```
public function actionSql(){
    $rows = (new Query())
    ->select(['ta.id', 'e.name', 'e.desc', 'u.place', 'u.date'])
    ->from(['ta' => 't_area'])
    ->innerJoin('event e', 'ta.id = e.t_area_id')
    ->innerJoin('ubic u', 'e.id = u.event_id')
    ->where([
        'ta.id' => 1,
        'dayname(u.date)' => 'Monday'
        ])
    ->all();
    //The solution is!: 
    return $rows;
}
```